# How to create new Hald Clut from an Image?

Tags: c#, .net, magick.net, imagemagick.net

Using the ImageMagick library, I am able to apply various hald cluts to images, but am looking for a way to use the library to create a new hald clut from an image.

I want to do this in C#, but open to any suggestions. I played with the ImageMagick command line tools and the Magick.NET, but could not figure out how to extract a hald clut.

Comment: The general technique is to create a base HALD image (all colors with no processing applied) using HALD:x. Save as PNG. Take the PNG image to some interactive tool like GIMP or Photoshop. Apply the same processing you want to do to an image to the HALD base image. Then save as a new PNG. Then bring back that new HALD image to Imagemagick and use -hald-clut to apply it to any image. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#hald-clut. Note that the HALD processing can only be global things like brightness, contrast, color changes. No convolutions, blurring or other local operations

Comment: CONTINUED: Given a single arbitrary image with no knowledge of how it was created/modified, there is no way that I know to derive the HALD clut image.

Comment: See also http://im.snibgo.com/edithald.htm

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think I would get an answer anywhere and here you covering both forums.